# how to GET value into bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table "on php page" that contain records from a database. At each row there is a button and when I click on the button, a modal bootstrap  should appear that contain details about members that you want to know.

This is the button code:

```
  <td> <?php echo '
         <a href="?id='.$tabel_id.'" class="btn btn-primary">details</a>'; ?> </td>
```

and the modal bootstrap code:

```
    <?php
       $connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','smart');
      $connect->set_charset("utf8");

      if(isset($_GET['id'])){
          $Mid = (int)$_GET['id'];
      $getid = "select * from members where id = '$Mid'";
      $runid = mysqli_query($connect, $getid);

      $row_id = mysqli_fetch_array($runid);

     $show_name = $row_id['name'];

     $show_number = $row_id['number'];



     ?>
    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> اضافة فاتورة</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

              <div class="container">
                  <div class="row">
                  <form action="" method="post">

                      <label>الاسم</label>
                      <input type="textbox" name="" class="Mname" disabled value="<?php echo $show_name  ?>"></input>
                      <label>الرقم</label>
                      <input type="textbox" name="" class="Mname" disabled value="<?php echo $show_number;  ?>"></input>
                      <label>النوع</label>
                      <select name="dbType" id="dbType">
                      <option value="normal">عادي</option>
                      <option value="uargent">مستعجل</option>
                      </select>
                      <div id="otherType" style="display:none;">
                      <label for="specify">Specify</label>
                      <input type="text" name="specify" placeholder="Specify Databse Type"/>
                      </div>



                     </form>
                  </div>
                </div>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 <?php }else{echo'select an row please';} ?>
      <script>

$("#myModal").modal("show");</script>

    <script src="/our/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/our/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>    
    <script src="/our/js/run.js"></script>  
</body>
```

But when I click on the add button the modal doesn't appear but the url changes like this:

> http://localhost/our/dashboard.php#myModal?id=2

Why doesn't the modal work?

Comment: where's the jQuery function / trigger ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** You have `data-toggle='modal'` but it doesn't know what modal it should open. Add this to your button.

```
data-target='#myModal'
```

[Source](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/)

---

**2.** This will also trigger the modal.

```
$("#myModal").modal("show");
```

---

You can't use click function in a link that redirect you.

Make normal link with only **href** attr.

```
<?php echo '<a href="?id=$tabel_id">Button</a>'; ?>
```

url should be dashboard?id=1

html

```
<?php if(isset($_GET["id"])) { ?>

    <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">    
        <!---Your same modal from your question--->    
    </div>    

<?php } ?>
```

add this before your `</body>` closing body tag

```
<script>$("#myModal").modal("show");</script>
```

Comment: i have puted the code above body tag but still not working

Comment: i'm a new on bootstrap please explain more Where should I put the code

Comment: the modal is work but modal-body is invisible i think so because my php 

`   $connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','smart');
   $connect->set_charset("utf8");
   
   if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $Mid = (int)$_GET['id'];
   $getid = "select * from members where id = '$Mid'";
   $runid = mysqli_query($connect, $getid);
   
   $row_id = mysqli_fetch_array($runid);
  
  $show_name = $row_id['name'];
  
  $show_number = $row_id['number'];
`

Comment: whats the #myModal in the url for?

Comment: i want to use $_GET['id'] from url so when the modal shows should url change to /dashboard.php#myModal?id=1 or 2 ....

Comment: but it could be /dashboard.php?id=1. #myModal has nothing to do with you php code

Comment: you mean you dont get results from mysql or the modal isn't working

Comment: i mean i don't get result from $_GET

see the button i putted this href="#myModal?id='.$tabel_id.'"

Comment: go to /dashboard?id=1 and add this after your modal <script>$("#myModal").modal("show")</script> and see if it works

Comment: if i write by my hand in the url  #myModal?id=1 it's work
but when click on buttens the modal shows but the modal-body is empty

Comment: modal-body empty because there is no id in url

Comment: hello my friend just i want to tell you something what i want exactly when the modal shows i want to change the url to #modal?id='.$tabel_id.'

but the url doesn't change 

`<?php echo '
    <a href="#myModal?id='.$tabel_id.'" class="btn btn-primary" scrolling="yes" data-toggle="modal">add</a>'; ?>`

Comment: if theres no id in the url can you show me how you get the $tabel_id

Comment: the question is how to make url changing?

Comment: `
        $connect = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','','smart');
               $connect->set_charset("utf8"); 

     $tabel = "select * from members";
 
 $run_tabel = mysqli_query($connect, $tabel);
 
 while($row_tabel = mysqli_fetch_array($run_tabel)){
  
  $tabel_id = $row_tabel['id'];
  
  $tabel_name = $row_tabel['name'];
  
  $tabel_number = $row_tabel['number'];
  
  $tabel_date = $row_tabel['add_date'];`

Comment: when click a button should see in url like this 

dashboard.php#myModal?id=1

but the url now like this:

dashboard.php

Comment: i edited my answer. Try to use that for testing. You can try to echo $tabel_id; to see if its working. it should echo out a number

Comment: thank you my friend for your helping but that's not my exactly problem 

my problem in the url bar i just want to change url to #myModal?id=$tabel_id when the button clicked  because i want use $_GET['$tabel_id'] in the modal....... to show Other details

Comment: does the url change at all? What is the exactly url after you clicked

Comment: when clicked the button the url still like this 

http://localhost/our/dashboard.php

this is the code :

`<td> <?php echo "
    <a href="#myModal?id='.$tabel_id.'" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary" scrolling="yes" data-toggle="modal">add</a>"; ?> `

Comment: try with only href attr delete all data-target and data-toggle etc... and see if it works

Comment: nothing happen but i have deleted data-target="#myModal" and the url changed like what i want but the modal didn't show up?

Comment: when bootstrap makes the modal function when you click the link it prevent you from redirecting. Even if the link works the modal won't show up. You cant get it work this way. There is a easier way

Comment: oh thank you my friend for your help i will try with a Different code

Comment: what the easier way please tell me

Comment: what did you mean for get you code in your question.

Make normal link with only href attr.

 <php echo '<a href="?id=$tabel_id">Button</a>'; <?php

Comment: when i add your code the url changing to http://localhost/our/dashboard.php?id=1 but the modal didn't show up

Comment: please try again

Comment: does the modal show up without php if statement around it. $("#myModal").modal("show") should open it

Comment: this is important. You have jQuery?

Comment: yes i have iquery and bootstrap

  <script src="/our/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/our/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="/our/js/run.js"></script>

Comment: anyway. you cant use your <a> link with click function